# How to have docker restart container with a completely new container?

Tags: docker

It seems like the --restart option for docker run will try to restart the exact same container which has stopped. I would like it to restart with a completely new container, as if I had just run the 'docker run' command again. Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 1):

Think of a docker "container" as an instance of a docker "image". Once you've created that instance it will live on with its state. If you want a new container you'll need to create a new one with the same image with "docker run".

If you have lots of parameters passed in when you create your container, you might want to checkout using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) for the behavior you want. That way you can create a `docker-compose.yml` file with all the parameters you use to create your container then run:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

This would manage creating the exact container you want each time.